# Wordpress custom query showing duplicate Results on frontend

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've made a custom search query on a woocommerce website. 
Everything looks good. But two search results are showing up when I search for something like an sku number.

**example search result**
Example -- http://bxcell.iteratemarketing.com/?s=BE0204&post_type=product

***HERE IS MY CODE***

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'woo_custom_fields_query');

    function woo_custom_fields_query($posts, $query = false) {
      if (is_search()){
        $noIds = array(0);
          foreach($posts as $post){
              $noIds[] = $post->ID;
          }

          $mPosts = get_post_by_custom_field(get_search_query(), $noIds);      

          if ($mPosts){
              foreach($mPosts as $product_id){
                  $posts[] = get_post($product_id->post_id);                
              }
          }
          return $posts;
      }
      return $posts;
    }

    function get_post_by_custom_field($qrval, $noIds) {
      global $wpdb, $wp_query;

      $pstArr = array();

      $noIdsQrl = implode(",", $noIds);
      $vrvspsts = $wpdb->get_results(
                      "
            SELECT p.post_parent as post_id FROM $wpdb->posts as p
            join $wpdb->postmeta pm
            on p.ID = pm.post_id         
            and pm.meta_value LIKE '%$qrval%'
            join $wpdb->postmeta visibility
            on p.post_parent = visibility.post_id    
            and visibility.meta_key = '_visibility'
            and visibility.meta_value <> 'hidden'
            where 1
            AND p.post_parent <> 0
            and p.ID not in ($noIdsQrl)
            and p.post_status = 'publish'
            group by p.post_parent
            "
      );

      foreach($vrvspsts as $post){
          $noIds[] = $post->post_id;
      }

      $noIdsQrl = implode(",", $noIds);

      $rglprds = $wpdb->get_results(
          "SELECT p.ID as post_id FROM $wpdb->posts as p
          join $wpdb->postmeta pm
          on p.ID = pm.post_id        
          AND pm.meta_value LIKE '%$qrval%' 
          join $wpdb->postmeta visibility
          on p.ID = visibility.post_id    
          and visibility.meta_key = '_visibility'
          and visibility.meta_value <> 'hidden'
          where 1
          and (p.post_parent = 0 or p.post_parent is null)
          and p.ID not in ($noIdsQrl)
          and p.post_status = 'publish'
          group by p.ID

    ");

      $pstArr = array_merge($vrvspsts, $rglprds);
      $wp_query->found_posts += sizeof($pstArr);    
      return $pstArr;
    }
```

***Thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, problem in your logic of two queries. You getting duplicate post ids in merged array from two results.

```
 $pstArr = array_unique(array_merge($vrvspsts, $rglprds));
```